# Looking to pivot non-numeric data in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, pivot

Hope someone can help here, I'm trying to pivot data in an SQL table. the table contains an ID, column name, and column value columns. I'm trying to pivot it from this:
[image]

To this:

[image]

I've reviewed a load of posts but the PIVOT command always seems to need numerical data or data that can be aggregated, mines has none of these.
Does anyone know how this can be accomplished or if PIVOT is the right command to use here?

====================================================

Managed to resolve the issue with the post that was provided:
[image]

```
    SELECT ItemID,
 MAX(CASE [ColumnName] WHEN 'CompanyCode' THEN [Value] END) AS [CompanyCode],
 MAX(CASE [ColumnName] WHEN 'CompanyName' THEN [Value] END) AS [CompanyName],
 MAX(CASE [ColumnName] WHEN 'SupplierCode' THEN [Value] END) AS [SupplierCode],
 MAX(CASE [ColumnName] WHEN 'SupplierName' THEN [Value] END) AS [SupplierName]
FROM dbo.CustomValuesText
GROUP BY ItemID
```

Comment: Use Max(), Min(), First(), or Last() when pivoting text values. Does assume each ID can have only 4 records as in your sample.

Comment: Thanks June. Managed to sort it. Updated post with solution.